# Do my colors work?

Tags: color, critique

I'm not much of a designer (yet), and I'm still in the learning phases. I'm not bad with Photoshop, but when it comes to color theory and typography, I'm not sure I have any idea. So, I just create things and play around with colors till they are visually appealing to me. But there are rules to colors, and I never know if I'm breaking them. This is an iOS interface I cooked up, and I wanted to know if the colors work together, or if I'm breaking any rules? What else am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: Not a fan of it myself,   Black against the dark colours does not stand out well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be its partially not the answer but i want you to judge,**self satisfaction is must in every work**

> **Everyone has a favorite color and they tend to choose their preferred
>   color when it comes to their work or
>   personal life, e.g. like buying an
>   item or doing an art work. This is
>   almost the same when it’s applied to
>   designers. Designers have a propensity
>   to use the same set of colors on their
>   design. Even if they were given an
>   unlimited range of colors, they would
>   rather still stick with their own
>   senses.**
>   [Nicely said on one extra pixel](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/11/03/anatomy-of-colors-in-web-design-green-and-environmental-concept/)

---

**In designing, everyone has their own perception regarding design and color; sometimes colors which I like, you won't like.**

***MAKE SURE THAT THE FOREGROUND CONTRASTS ENOUGH WITH THE BACKGROUND COLOR.***

- [You can check your website/image contrast](http://www.checkmycolours.com/) I often use this.
- [You can grab any color from any image by using this](http://www.degraeve.com/color-palette/index.php)

You must read these color guidelines:

1. [Little knowledge of colors](http://www.vanseodesign.com/web-design/color-meaning/)
2. [Please please everyone read this article on colors it helped me a lot](http://www.allgraphicdesign.com/graphicsblog/2008/03/24/color-theory-in-graphic-design-web-design-how-to-combine-colors-choose-color-schemes-part-iii/)
3. [Find the Perfect Colors for Your Website/Design](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/design/find-the-perfect-colors-for-your-website/) You Must read all these articles

Comment: I personally wouldn't say "must" (especially in art related fields). I would say that "color rules" are more like "color guidelines"

Comment: #2 had good content, but that page gave me the eye-cramps

Comment: same here :|...

Comment: #2 _is_ interesing: "Look below at the corporate Samsung Logo: Sony."

Answer (score 4):

I am not a color expert myself but I can try and give you a few tips maybe. The design looks "OK" to me.
I'll try and give you some advice, it might not be the best one but... play around...

I think you are using to many colors and they look a bit "dirty" you might want to make them a little brighter and cleaner.

The brown in the background looks bright enough but maybe to bright, you could try and loose some saturation or add a little green into it maybe so it looses saturation...the best thing I would do, I would loose the brown in the background and replace it with some shade of desaturated grey, not to bright but not to dark...and I think this will help the other colors in the design aswell.

The teal looks a bit dirty and dark, it gets better on the edges, you can try and make it a little brighter or something.

The same for the green, it looks a bit dark and dirty, try and add some brightness to it.

The purple is too bright and saturated in comparasion with the other colors and it definetly stands out, probably because of the brown background also.

You might already know about this but a pretty handy tool I use when I choose colors is [kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com)

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can do a lot worse than to go to your local art supply store and buy a color wheel. It will include a basic introduction to color harmony, and it's a physical tool that you can play around with when looking for color ideas. There's a good introductory article on the color wheel and its use at the [Liquisoft website](http://colortheory.liquisoft.com/).

Kuler is a good resource that's built right into Photoshop, as you've discovered, but it becomes a great deal more useful when you know what the terms "monochromatic," "complementary," "split" and "triadic" actually mean. Don't underestimate the power of getting the terminology under your belt. If you don't understand the words used to describe things, you'll never get the concepts.

My constant mantra to beginning designers is: Find things that you recognize as good, or particularly like, and figure out why they work. Try to duplicate them, so you develop your own personal "library" of techniques and ideas. With a bit of theory study and lots of practice, you will develop your own feel for color, and once you've practiced following the rules and are comfortable that you understand them, you will know when you can and need to break them.